# How can I kick the user if I change IsConfirmed column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, logout, simplemembership

I use ASP.NET SimpleMembership..

My scenario;

The user login and then I change IsConfirmed column to false on webpages_Membership table..
And the user try to change page, the login page seems to the user..

Comment: Are you trying to use the isConfirmed column to disable the account? If so the user could potentially set it back if you are using an email confirmation and they click on the link again. Probably better to add an "Enabled" column to the user profile. It is not clear from your description, but are you trying to deny the user access immediately upon changing this column?

Comment: I dont use email confirmation so I think it doesnt problem.. But you are right thank you for extra information..

And Yessss, I am trying to deny the user access immediately upon changing this column..

Comment: I do not know of any way to immediately notify the ASP.NET application/session of a database change. I think the best you can do is to always authenticate the user (or at a minimum check that column/flag) ever time you authorize them to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I user Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax.. Because my application needs authenticate on all pages..

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
        {
            if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                bool isConfirmed = (..your codes here..)
                if (isConfirmed == false)
                {
                    WebSecurity.Logout();    
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your most sensible options are to use any of the authentication related steps in Global.asax.cs, or to [derive from `AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#deriving_from_authorizeattribute). Given that non-confirmed users are going to have to get to *somewhere* (for example in order to confirm their account) then you probably don't want the former. With either approach their next request will get denied.

Therefore, I would just extend your `[Authorize]` attribute to do something like the following, and just use that in the appropriate Controllers and Actions instead of `[Authorize]` (*I'm assuming C# as you didn't specify language in your tags*):

```cs
public class AuthorizeIfConfirmedAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)) return false;

        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user = httpContext.User.Identity;
        return WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(user.Name);
    }
}

[AuthorizeIfConfirmed]
public class MyController { ... }
```

(If you want to use a custom property on your `UserProfile` class instead of `IsConfirmed` then you can simply adjust this code accordingly).

The advantage of this approach is that it keeps all your authorization logic in the usual place, and you can also combine it with role enforcement, e.g.:

```cs
[AuthorizeIfConfirmed(Roles = "admin")]
public class MyController { ... }
```

Note that if you use WebApi or SignalR you may have to include these checks in however you are performing request authorization for the apis as well.

Comment: @dustqm. Then this will work, just use this attribute on all your controllers or register it as a [global filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx) (which is becoming best practice anyway). The advantage of this as opposed to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` is that you can combine it with other Authorize attributes and have a common method of doing authorization across your entire site (e.g. enforcing admin roles for some controllers).